# saving html & sign in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to work out, how I save & signs, I need this due to our customers business sometime have the & sign instead of and.

I thought it might be a `preg` thing but i am not sure

Comment: Can you post some code that shows the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problems storing ampersands in your database (unless it's Oracle).

When displaying the data in an HTML page, make sure you encode it appropriately, eg

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['col'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') ?>
```

Comment: But make sure you always *save* it in raw form (although blahblahblah `mysql_real_escape_string()`).

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a problem storing ampersands in the database as &. When you retrieve the data from the database, you should convert HTML entities before displaying them in the browser. So `&` would become `&amp;` in your HTML source.